# SAS Connection to DB2 Via ODBC Error

Tags: db2, odbc, sas

I have been working in SAS connecting to DB2 via ODBC for a while now and this PROC SQL step generally works:

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc(dsn=DSQ user="UserID" password="Password"); 
execute (set current degree = 'ANY' ) by ODBC;
create table tempTable as select * from connection to odbc (
    select * 
    from schemaName.tableName
);
quit;
```

However, occassionally I get the following error, and when I get this error I won't be able to run another ODBC query for quite some time because everytime I try to run the query I get the same error:

```
ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system
   error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004
```

After some time the error either resolves itself or I do something that I am not aware of that fixes the issue. This is a very frustrating issue and since I never know how long this issue is going to persist I would like a more robust solution to this issue. I have checked the db2diag.log file and here is the part that describes this error:

```
2015-06-03-08.17.34.345000-300 I60888H446           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 4452                 TID : 7804           PROC : sas.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: 
EDUID   : 7804
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, Cryptography, cryptDynamicLoadGSKitCrypto, probe:998
MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000007=-1879048185=ECF_UNKNOWN
          Unknown
DATA #1 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
60
DATA #2 : String, 11 bytes
gsk8sys.dll
```

I was trying to find an example to put in this post so I ran this snippet of code in SAS to see if the error would come back, however it seemed to have resolved the error because after running this piece of code, I ran the initial code and it worked. Here is the code that seemed to have resolved the issue.

```
proc sql;
    connect to odbc(dsn=DSQ user="UserID" password="Password"); 
    execute (set current degree = 'ANY' ) by ODBC;
    create table column_names as select * from connection to odbc (
        select * from sysibm.syscolumns
    );
quit;
```

I have tried googling this issue, but there isn't much help on this particular error. Is there any reason that the second SAS code would have fixed the issue I was having? Is there any way to fix this problem so it won't come back in the future?

Please note, when the error occurs, I am still able to run queries via ODBC in Microsoft Access without any problems. It appears this is an issue with just a particular instance.

System Setup:

Windows 7 64-bit

SAS 9.3 (32)

DB2 v10.5.300.125

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update:
On a few occasions, I was able to go into task manager and delete some processes that were still running and then this issue would resolve itself, however today when this problem occurred, those processes weren't there. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you also have some other IBM products installed that may be using GSKit libraries? Lotus Notes, for example? The error in `db2diag.log` suggests that DB2 cannot load `gsk8sys.dll`, which it uses for authentication.

Comment: Do you have any sort of connection limiting controls on your ODBC server?  I wonder if you're running a lot of these and it is forcing you to not connect so frequently (and it's coming back as an odd error that doesn't make sense), preventing connections for an hour or something as a protection from Denial of Service attacks or brute force attacks.  (This would mostly apply if you run a lot of these in sequence and it tends to occur after the tenth or twentieth or whatever run.)

Comment: Yes, I use Lotus Notes as well on the machine. I did a search of the C drive and couldn't find the 'gsk8sys.dll' file. However, I did find a 'gsk8iccs.dll' file in the 'Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\icc' folder. Could this be what is causing my issue?

Comment: Joe-Would that be instance specific? Because I am able to run queries via ODBC in Access while I am getting this error in SAS.

Comment: I'm not sure - this is just speculation on my part, I don't know much about that sort of server configuration.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Windows event log at the time of error, related to `gsk8ver.exe` and/or `gsk8ver_64.exe`?

Comment: Also, search your disk to see if there are other copies of `gsk8iccs.dll` that may belong to other software products (potentially Notes, may be others).

Comment: I didn't see anything in the Windows event log at the time of the error related to any of the gsk8ver files and there are no other gsk8iccs.dll files on my computer. There were two warnings in the Windows event log around the time this started. There is one for event ID 1014, DNS Client Events and one for event ID 40961 LSA(LsaSrv) and then a little while later I got event ID 5719 NETLOGON. Could any of these be the issue?

Comment: I did find that I don't have the gsk8 folder in the C:\PROGRA~2\IBM folder and therefore the gsk8ver.exe file didn't even exist. I copy and pasted the folder from someone else onto my computer and I'm still running into the same error. I edited the PATH system variable to include the gsk8\BIN and gsk8\icc folders. Do I need to setup a certificate after I get the folder there? And if so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The symptom may be depended on the installation order of Db2 connect and a program (sas.exe). If DB2 connect is installed first, it should not be occurred.  So it is suggested to remove and re-install both products once then install Db2 connect first.

Hope this helps.